# "На хуторе" или "в хуторе"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

У Гоголя слово "Хутор" употребляется с предлогом на. Но в большинстве случаев с указанием населенного пункта употребляется предлог "в". Так, как правильно: "на хуторе" или "в хуторе"? Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

У Гоголя правильно. )))
Т.е. встречаются оба варианта. *"Уже четыре года, как Иван Федорович Шпонька в отставке и живет в хуторе своем Вытребеньках".*  Возможно, сказывается влияние украинского, где эти предлоги в большой степени взаимозаменяемы.

В отношении "большинства случаев" - да, в современном языке предлог В практически вытеснил НА в сочетании с городом, деревней, селом и проч. Но раньше они конкурировали. Вспомните "На деревню, дедушке".

Почему хутор сохранил исходный вариант "на хуторе", сказать не берусь. Может потому, что хутор воспринимается скорее не как населённый пункт, а как хозяйственная единица.

Answer (score 2):

Всё дело, наверное, в том, что хутор - это прежде всего земельный участок.  Поэтому просится предлог НА.

Толковый словарь русского языка под ред. Д. Н. Ушакова:

ХУТОР - хутора. малый или мужской род (от венгерское, мадьярское; слово мадьярского происхождения hatar). Обособленный земельный участок с усадьбой владельца.

Словарь Ожегова:
хутор - обособленный земельный участок с усадьбой владельца Выселиться на хутор.